# Old unsolved question on greens function

Tags: differential-equations, calculus, greens-functions

So I was looking up Kf Riley’s 3rd edition, and bump into a problem about greens function. I went online and googled and notice other people had the same problem and no one really could answer:

Continuity of Green's function and its derivatives https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2403134/continuity-of-greens-function-and-its-derivatives

Continuity in derivatives of the Green's function in RHB
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173174/continuity-in-derivatives-of-the-greens-function-in-rhb?rq=1

I suspect this is likely as there is some “hand waving” involve. Otherwise, why would the nth derivative tend to infinity, (n-1) derivative be discontinuous and (n-2) onwards is continuous?

Is there some sort of intuition behind it? If not, why didn’t the authors devote some time to explaining it?

Any reference or direction appreciated

Comment: Source: pg512 K.F. Riley 3rd edition

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Its more of a statement in the book actually. Not really a question, if you click the links I presented above, you can see the statement that is in question. Why does the nth derivative go to infinity? N-1 derivative discontinuous and n-2 on wards continuous?

Comment: This is because you are really looking at distributions, not functions. The Greens function is a solution of $D G(x) =\delta(x)$, where $D$ is the differential operator for the problem, e.g. Laplace or Klein-Gordon operator in the common physics applications. These statements are not hand-waving but can be proven using the theory of distributions. Of course you need to make certain assumptions on the test functions, they are usually taken to be either $C^\infty$ with compact support or in the Schwartz space. If you take freaky test functions, the above statements may not hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really handwaving but has been made precise. The point is thate you are really looking at distributions, not functions. After all, the Greens function is a solution of
$$ D\,G(x)=\delta(x)\;,$$
where $D$ is the differential operator for the problem. In physics applications $D$ is often the Laplace or Klein-Gordon operator. Even though physicists sometimes refer to $\delta$ as $\delta$-function, $\delta$ is indeed a distribution, and so is $G$. To have a real justification you need to look at some intro to the theory of functions. But of course you can get a feeling for what's going on by recalling that the function $f(x)=|x|$ is smooth,  $f'(x)=2\theta(x)-1$ and therefore $f''(x)=2\delta(x)$. Now you are looking for a $G$ that satisfies $\partial_x^nG(x)\sim\delta(x)$, where $n$ is the order of $D$. The above example of $f$, $f'$ and $f''$ then suggests that if $\partial_x^nG(x)$ has infinites, i.e. goes like $\delta$, then $\partial_x^{n-1}G(x)$ should go like $\theta$, i.e. jump, and $\partial_x^{n-2}G(x)$ like $|x|$, i.e. be continuous. These statements can be made precise. Of course you need to make certain assumptions on the test functions, they are usually taken to be either in $C^\infty$ with compact support or in the Schwartz space. If you choose to use freaky test functions, the above statements may not hold.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can i ask, in your example you showed that if $f(x) = |x|$, then $f'(x) = 2\theta(x)-1$ and therefore $f''(x) = 2\delta(x)$. Why is this so? Isn't $f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} |x| = x/|x|?$

Comment: Also, can i ask why if $f(x) = |x|$, $f'(x) = 2\theta(x) -1$ and $f''(x) = 2\delta(x)$, then $\partial^n_x G(x)$ has infinities? Is this some theory of distribution? Any references i can look at? Can't find anything on google

Comment: @AkiraD.Soul Do you agree that $x/|x|=\text{sign}\, x=2\theta(x)-1$? [Here](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~seri/homepage/courses/Analysis2008.pdf) are some notes on distribution theory.

Comment: Is your $\theta(x)$ then heaviside step function? If so then yes. So the derivative of the heviside is the Dirac delta?

Comment: @AkiraD.Soul Yes. (I could have added that but thought it was clear from the context.) In the math literature Greens functions are usually called fundamental solutions.

Comment: Okay sure! I don’t quite get it yet, but I think from your answers the reason for the behaviour of the greens functions and it’s derivatives requires some knowledge of distributions which I do not have. But I will read it up. Thanks anyway!